# how to create a callback function node js

Tags: node.js, callback

I have a flag , named 'flag', and when this flag get's a specific value , I want to invoke a specific function.
anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: You can't, you need infrastructure to invoke callbacks when values change

Comment: Just call the function instead of setting the flag.

Comment: @Raynos: No; he can use properties

Comment: Is the flag the property of an object? You could use a setter...

Answer (score 3):

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var flags = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
Object.defineProperty(flags, "someFlag", {
  get: function () {
    return this._someFlag;
  },
  set: function (v) {
    this._someFlag = v;
    this.emit("someFlag", v);
  }
});

flags.on("someFlag", callback);
```